# MySQL not updating on duplicate key

Tags: mysql, indexing, duplicates, unique

Hi, I'm having trouble with this query:

```
$size = isset($_POST['size'])
  ? "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['size'])."'"
  : "NULL";

$color = isset($_POST['color'])
  ? "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['color'])."'"
  : "NULL";

if (is_numeric($_POST['productID']) && is_numeric($_POST['amount']))
{           
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO usercart VALUES ('', '"
  .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_ID'])."', '"
  .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productID'])."', "
  .$size." , ".$color." , '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount'])."')"
  ." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + '"
  .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount'])."'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

In my MySQL table I have a unique index named `"product"` on `productID`, `userID`, `size` and `color`. But when I run this query it just inserts instead of updating the amount. Reading the MySQL documentation I can and should not have to specify the index name.

Been fiddling around with this for hours now. So anyone knows whats up?

Comment: Can you list the entries that are now duplicate in table usercart w.r.t. the index? And double check that the index also requires uniqueness?

Comment: The structure:http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/3494/dbuniqueerror01rjw.jpg    

And the entries:
http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/6959/dbuniqueerror02.jpg

Comment: Both entries are created using the same query as posted above. With as you can see, the exact same values.

Comment: BTW: it would be easier for most of us if you'd added the table definitions in plain SQL inside the post, instead of linking to some graphical display snapshot thingy.

Comment: @wildplasser well, i did that below the code block. Images just there so anyone can see if i missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULL is always considered unique. So if you set either color or size to null the tuple you're inserting will be considered unique as far as your unique constraints are concerned.

Comment: So how do i work around this? I need the table to update even if the values are NULL. I rather not change the DB to not accept nulls and enter "null" as a string or something to replace it.

Comment: This indeed is the answer: making size and color NOT NULLable, and allowing some fake value for it (eg 0 and 'none' ) . Extra: if you cannot change the data model, you could still enforce NOT NULL in the application, eg by `COALESCE(safequote($color), 'None' )`

Comment: NULL is always unique, that's just the way it is. The changes you just mentioned is the way to solve your problem. I don't know any other way. Why do you want to keep the NULL values?

Comment: That sucks, plenty of stuff to replace with this approach. Howver i can always check manually if there is going to be a duplicate, this adds a little overheat but it will manage. Still i find it strange why mysql acts like this.

Comment: Enforcing it by means of the schema is less work, and better.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a surrogaat key "cart_id", which is also auto increment as the first field. Your fragment will probably result in the DBMS trying to enter user_id into the first field, which is cart_id. 
Try using a designated insert, omitting the cart_id, like:

```
INSERT INTO usercart(user_id, product_id, ... )
VALUES (user_id, product_id, ...)
   ;
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work: 
 INSERT INTO usercart (userID, productID, size, color, amount) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_ID'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productID'])."', ".$size." , ".$color." , '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount'])."')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount'])."'

Comment: Though it is not the solution to your problem, it is still advisable to name the fields, instead of trusting on the order of fields.

Comment: Ow, and why is that? I always used it like this. I can trust the order of the fields as long as i don't change them, in which case naming the fields won't work either if the field does not have a default value.

Comment: Because the order is *strictly speaking* undefined, even if you trust it.